# How can i group billno in laravel nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

[image: Laravel Nova]
Larvel Nova Index
[image: Database]
How can i group billno in laravel nova

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you can do that with the indexQuery Method on your Nova model.

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/authorization.html#index-filtering

The other option is doing it with Lenses:
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/lenses/defining-lenses.html